# PHP - How do I insert a linebreak into a mail body?

Tags: php

I'm sending this:

```
$message = "1001"."\r\n";
$message .= "username"."\r\n";
$message .= "email"."\r\n";
$message .= "customdata"."\r\n";
```

And receiving an email that looks like this:

```
1001 username email customdata
```

I need it to look like this:

```
1001 
username 
email 
customdata
```

Why is the linebreak not working? I'm sending the emails from a Linux mail server and receiving in Windows. I've just moved the code from one hosting to another and stopped working.

Comment: you can use <br> tag

Comment: Are you sending HTML email or plain text emails

Comment: I can't use <br>, the emails sent are filtered and parsed in c# and <br> it breaks the whole code

Comment: I'm sending the mail in both, html and plain text (AltBody)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply:

```
<?php

$message = '
1001
username
email
customdata
';

?>
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is what i used once in a non-html email situation!

Comment: Yes, tried it, not working neither. It's really strange, I've used \r\n for 10 years and suddenly it doesn't work.

Comment: well \r\n is supposed to be the standard... By the way you are using php mail function ? or PHPMailer ?

Comment: I was using mail() function, couldn't get the \r\n too work, so I've changed to PHPMailer class and now it works as it should

Comment: Nice ! Thats why i asked, i always use PHPMailer, and i almost never have any trouble... It's still weird that switching to a new server broke your mailing code...

Answer (score -1):

Hi since a mail is written with html you also need to use those tags

try use "br" tag for newline

Comment: I can't use <br>